# Should we have a culture of requiring references?

Tags: discussion

Do we need/want a culture of requiring references for expert opinions on outdoors?  Are outdoor skills the kind of thing for which canonical references are even available?

Answer (score 6):

I would say references should be required when controversial (when someone disagrees with you on an objective point you've made) and encouraged where relevant, but not necessarily required in all cases.

Questions arguing about legality for instance, or those debating health I believe should always have references to back them up where they're available. Questions about the best qualities to look for in walking sticks - perhaps not.

Comment: I like this viewpoint.  It isolates out the part I would have concern over which are one line "do you have references" comments on first answers, etc. but also leaves room for those cases where references really do improve things

Answer (score 2):

I thing that standards do exist in Outdoor activities but not all questions can relate to those standards.

For example, questions related to equipments (brands) are hard to answer. On the other hand, what kind of clothing to wear when it is cold, humid, hot can be easily answered no matter where the person is.